# ImportError during python run

Tags: python-import, importerror, python-3.7

Currently I am executing doamusic python codes from 
  https://github.com/yump/doamusic.git

I am using python 3.7.2. (Python IDLE) on windows.

My directory tree is
F:\doamusic_project\doamusic\music.py

when I run music.py, I am getting the following error

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "F:\doamusic_project\doamusic\music.py", line 31, in 
    from . import util

File "..\doamusic__init__.py", line 1, in 
    from doamusic.music import *

File "..\doamusic\music.py", line 32, in 
    from . import _music

ImportError: cannot import name '_music' from 'doamusic' (..\doamusic__init__.py)

What is the reason for not importing _music ?.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do an import from .pyx file. A .pyx file must be compiled unlike a .py file.

Try to do that before the import of _music:

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
```

More info [Cython](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html)